# General Registry failed to update in Julia

Tags: julia

I just launched Julia and tried to add a package and then it gave the following error:

```
┌ Warning: Some registries failed to update:
│     — /Users/logankilpatrick/.julia/registries/General — failed to fetch from repo
└ @ Pkg.Types /Users/sabae/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/Pkg/src/Types.jl:1199
```

Any thoughts to resolve this? I don't think I made any recent changes to this and I am running on Julia 1.3.0 right now.

EDIT:

This is the output of the registry status command:

```
(v1.3) pkg> registry st
Registry Status 
 [23338594] General (https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure as to the root cause of why this occurred but the following [basic steps from the Pkg docs](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/registries/) resolved the issue:

```
(v1.3) pkg> registry rm General
  Removing registry `General` from ~/.julia/registries/General

(v1.3) pkg> registry add https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General
   Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General"
     Added registry `General` to `~/.julia/registries/General`

(v1.3) pkg> registry up General
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General`
```

Comment: I was having random segfault while updating General registry and removing and re-adding magically fixed the issue. Thanks!